# Passing the referrer to omniture in server-side code

Tags: referrer, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to implement some omniture requests on server-side. I've got the calls set up, and the requests make it to omniture, but the referrer is not showing up in omniture.

Here is an example of one of the urls for omniture my code creates. Am I missing something?

http://[id].112.2o7.net/b/ss/[group]/1/H23.2/s1328206514850?AQB=1&ndh=1&ns=[id]&g=http%3A%2F%2F[domain]%2Flogin.asp&vid=1328206514850&pageName=Login%20Page%20!test!&r=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com

Answer (score 1):

The Internal URL Filters in the Report Suite Admin Console specifies what your internal domains are (i.e your domains). Any referal from any other domain will be recognised as a referrer.

I generally use a Firefox addon like WATS to debug the variables that are on a particular page, including referrer.

Keep in mind that there needs to be a referral from an external site. If you just type in the URL, or reload, or click from your own site, there is no referral. When testing this, I would create a page on another domain (e.g. localhost), and create a link to my page.

https://omniture-help.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1652/kw/JavaScript/related/1
COMPARISON: s.linkInternalFilters vs. Internal URL Filters

s.linkInternalFilters: The linkInternalFilters variable within the s_code.js file is used in exit link tracking. If s.trackExternalLinks is set to true, it is used to determine if a specific link a visitor clicked on is internal to your organization's site or not. Clicked links that match a value in s.linkInternalFilters are ignored, while links that do not match any values are sent to SiteCatalyst as an exit link.

Internal URL Filters: The Internal URL filters within the Admin Console is used in Traffic Sources reports, such as the Referring Domain report. Every s.t() request checks to see if the referring URL (contained within the referrer variable) matches any of the rules set up. Referring URLs that match any of these rules are excluded from all Traffic Sources reports, while referring URLs that do not are included.

It is recommended that s.linkInternalFilters and Internal URL filters match eachother, however the two operate completely independently and serve completely different functions.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of that image is the referrer value, r= . Is that the correct value? Also you should check your Internal URL Filters in the admin console for that report suite. Typically for new report suites you will find the value of . (a single period) set in there. If you do have that then no referrers will be recorded.